# Does the Arizona bill grant a religious exemption to discrimination laws?

Tags: united-states, religion, civil-rights, discrimination, arizona

The Arizona state legislature has just passed a bill called SB 1062, designed to protect religious liberty.  Opponents claim that it will allow businesses to refuse to serve people on the grounds of race, gender, orientation, etc. if it's done by the owner on religious grounds.  But the Civil Rights Act of 1964 prohibits discrimination in public accommodations (i.e. places of business accessible to the public, like restaurants and stores).  And it seems that Arizona state law contains [a similar prohibition](https://www.azag.gov/discrimination/public-accommodation-discrimination) on public accommodations discrimination.

So my question is, does SB 1062 grant a religious exemption to at least Arizona's state laws governing discrimination in public accommodations?  And how it would square with the federal Civil Rights law?  Does it only shield Arizona businesses from state-level prosecution of religiously motivated discrimination, but still leave them liable to federal  discrimination prosecutions?

Edit: this is somewhat of a moot point now, because Arizona Governor Jan Brewer has just vetoed the bill.  She cited this as her reason: "Religious liberty is a core American and Arizonan value, but so too is non-discrimination."

Comment: Short answer, no. Imagine this scenario - I'm a Jewish photographer. KKK or Neo-Nazis want me to come to their parade or whatever and record the entire thing. A bill like SB 1062 will allow me to say "no" to them. Without that, I'm forced to. And she vetoed it because she was pressured.

Comment: @Shahar I'm not asking about photographers; that's a different issue.  I'm asking about discrimination in public accomodations, like stores and restaurants.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - that's laywering. If I own a restaurant, I own a restaurant. Calling it "public" doesn't change the concept that I'm being forced to use MY OWN business resources to serve KKK

Comment: @DVK My question isn't about whether civil rights laws are a good thing.  It's about how SB 1062 would affect civil rights laws.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan It's a huge mess and there are lots of lawsuits about similar cases... In 2008, ShopRite in New Jersey denied making a cake that says "Happy Birthday Adolph Hitler" to a 3-year old who's name is Adolph Hitler. I'm not sure what the outcome was, but it definitely is a tough political question.

Comment: @Shahar Again, that's not the kind of thing I'm asking about.  I'm asking about public accommodations discrimination, meaning where a business like a restaurant or store kicks someone out on account of race, gender, orientation, etc.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yeah, I understand; I wrote another comment addressing that but I forgot to press send. Kicking someone out on account of race/gender/orientation is in many places not legal. That being said, having laws that people would call "discriminatory" or "anti-gay" (i.e. not allowing two people of the same sex to kiss, etc.) is legal. But still, there are many debates over that. Again with the same problem, if I have my own restaurant and a bald guy with a swastika walks on, must I serve him?

Comment: @shahar you are absolutely *not* forced to serve the KKK. They are not a protected class. So this proposed law had nothing to do with your imagined scenario.

Comment: No wonder Church of the Creator (COTC) appeared in the US.

Comment: @user4012 - Wrong. If you are running a business you don't get to pick and choose. Even privately owned businesses, if generally used by/available to the public, are "public accommodations."

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - yes, according to current nanny state laws, they are. The moral point still stands - whether you choose to violate my freedom by honestly calling it "I have the power", or by dressing it into lawyery "public accomodations" language which does not explain why MY business is all over the sudden "public"

Comment: @user4012 - The status of a business as a public accommodation is not a new phenomenon.  Nor is the idea that running a business is a privilege that society allows, not an inherent right. You can see that by the regulations and licensing requirements that have always existed for businesses.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet To be fair, plenty of people do believe that such regulations and licensing requirements stifle small businesses and are an unnecessary burden.

Comment: @JAB - I want a unicorn and to eat all the candy I want with no ill effects. That desire doesn't change the reality of how it is, and how it has been through time.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet you could at least get your unicorn eventually if you invest in genetic engineering research.

Comment: @JAB - but I want one **NOW**

Comment: @JAB - Wow. And there it is - my unicorn...LOL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. According to Wikipedia:

> "The bill would amend an existing law to give any individual or legal entity an exemption from any state law that substantially burdens their exercise of religion, including Arizona law requiring public accommodation regardless of a customer's race, color, national origin, sex, religion, and disability. Arizona has no public accommodation discrimination law protecting sexual orientation. The law being amended already gives a religious exemption to religious assemblies or institutions."

The proposed law does not seem to be a violation of the Civil Rights Act, due to an act of Congress passed in 1993 to "prevent laws that substantially burden a person's free exercise of their religion" called the [Religious Freedom Restoration Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_Freedom_Restoration_Act). The intention of the original law includes protections provided in the Civil Rights Act of 1964 if it substantially burdens a business, person, or trust to comply. The Religious Freedom Restoration Act was ruled unconstitutional for use by state or city governments, so the State Religious Freedom Restoration Acts were passed. Currently 17 states have such laws and several, including Arizona, have proposed them.

Comment: Do you have any idea whether the bill overrides Arizona's own public accomodations discrimination law?

Comment: This is what Wikipedia says and numerous news accounts, so it seems to be the idea. Its an anti-LBGT bill

Comment: It looks like you're right.  The Wikipedia article says "The bill would amend an existing law to give any individual or legal entity an exemption from any state law that substantially burdens their exercise of religion, including Arizona law requiring public accommodation regardless of a customer's race, color, national origin, sex, religion, and disability. Arizona has no public accommodation discrimination law protecting sexual orientation. The law being amended already gives a religious exemption to religious assemblies or institutions."  Could you add that quote to your answer?

Comment: OK, thanks!  By the way, I think the list you're referring to may be the list of states under Section 5 of the Voting Right Act, but the Supreme Court recently ruled that enforcement of section 5 preclearance is unconstitutional until Congress reexamines the list of states it applies to.

Comment: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shelby_County_v._Holder. And I think that list was only for voting-related offenses, because those states in the Deep South have a history of restricting voting abilities of minorities.

Comment: The Civil Rights Act of 1964 is not part of the constitution... So the law, if enacted, may be in violation of the CRA, but unless that act is adopted as an amendment to the constitution then it would not be unconstitutional based on that law.  Wikipedia is a good source for general reference but in cases like this something more authoritive is preferred.

Comment: @Chad If a state passes a law that contravenes federal law, then that violates the Supremacy Clause in Article Six of the Constitution.

Comment: @Shahar Read my edit. Wikipedia was fine. I was just in a rush and didn't read the entire article completely.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I've made some serious errors here. I should be providing the correct answer now

Comment: @Guest Arizona already has a state-level RFRA law.  See here: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Religious_Freedom_Restoration_Acts

Comment: It looks like SB 1062 would have gone even farther than Arizona's existing RFRA bill in allowing discrimination in public accomodation.  Jan Brewer just vetoed the bill, and she cited this as her reason: "Religious liberty is a core American and Arizonan value, but so too is non-discrimination."

Comment: Rugged individuality is an American value too :) RFRA says that unless the state has a "compelling interest" people should be allowed to practice their religion freely. So the bill is supposed to be a logical extension. It matters if we still need the Civil Rights Act or society as a whole is tolerant enough without it and if a few "religious" people want to do whatever, that's ok?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I assume a lot by saying a "few." I think this bill is way more about religious peoples right to discriminate against each other and this might easily get out of hand. I like to be able to go to a hotel and not worry someone will ask me to show my marriage certificate or thrown out of the deli because my skirt is too short. So many possibilities...

Answer (score 3):

> But the Civil Rights Act of 1964 prohibits discrimination in public accommodations (i.e. places of business accessible to the public, like restaurants and stores).

The [Civil Rights Act of 1964](http://www.ourdocuments.gov/doc.php?flash=true&doc=97&page=transcript) prohibits discrimination based on “race, color, religion, sex, or national origin”.  Note the lack of mention of “sexual orientation”.  So there is no conflict with this particular federal law.

Comment: But I don't think SB 1062 was only about discrimination based on orientation.  I think it was about granting an religious exemption to the prohibition against public accomodations discrimination in general.

Comment: Yes. It's granting a blanket exemption. The argument is that its meant to target LBGT, but that's not the only people it can be used against.